# Adjust volume for one audio file while two audio files are playing - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-audiomanager

I am trying to stream one audio file for the background music. Say, if the user presses the button, it will play another audio file while lowering the background music. I tried to use `AudioManager`, but it changes both of the volumes.

And here is my java file:

```java
public static void main(Context contex){

    //set the background music, first audio file
    //start the music when the activity starts
    MediaPlayer mediaplayer_background = new MediaPlayer().create(context, R.raw.background);
    /*
       audioManager_backgroud.setStreamVolume(
           AudioManager.STREAM_RING,
           //mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING),
           10,
           0
       );*/
    mediaplayer_background.start();

    //set the button music, second audio file
    MediaPlayer mediaplayer_button = new MediaPlayer().create(context, R.raw.clicksound);

    //Set the button on touch listener
    //if the user touch the button, it will play 
    binding.button1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            // if the user stop touching the button, the audio file for this button will stop
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                if (mediaplayer_button.isPlaying() == true) {
                    mediaplayer_button.pause();

                }

                //When the user touch the button, change the color of the button to the gray
                //start the second audio file
            } else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

                binding.button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                if (mediaplayer_button.isPlaying() == false) {
                    mediaplayer_button.start();

                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could use a library like Piasy/AudioMixer?